# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')1

Tags: reactjs, django

```
const loadAllProducts = () => {
  41 |   Object(_helper_coreapicalls__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["getProducts"])().then(data => {
> 42 |     if (data.error) {
     |              ^  43 |       setError(data.error);
  44 |       console.log(error);
  45 |     }
```

Comment: your data variable is emtpy, make sure it is populated or do a optional rendor with ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.